# python threading why I can use global variable outside the thread only once

Tags: python, multithreading

I'd like to use variable a outside my thread. In this example, I was expecting the program to print "a" every time after "update()" runs. I got "a" to print once, but that was it, I can see "updating" printed every second, so I know my thread is running properly, but I simply can't get what's in the thread out. Why?

```
import threading

a = 1

def update():
 global a
 a += 1
 print ("updating")
 threading.Timer(1, update).start()

update()
print(a)
```

I saw some codes that start the thread outside the thread itself:

```
def update():
 global a
 a += 1
 print ("updating")

threading.Timer(1, update).start()
update()
```

But I tried that, it just wouldn't work in my case. I only get "updating" printed out twice. I think it should be within the function so that you can restart the thread at the end of each call. Correct?

Or is it that I am not declaring variable correctly?

Comment: In your first version, you only print `a` once. Why do you think it should output multiple times?

Comment: and in the second snippet you're printing only "updating" - why would you expect it to print anything else ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Alright .. I'm coming from Arduino world and I was mistakenly expecting that rest of the codes are in a main loop that just repeats itself.. so print(a) was only called once .. I see

Comment: @alfasin I saw something like that elsewhere when someone explained how to use threading.. So my first snippet is correct? I was hoping update() to run every one second asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first block of code, you only print the value of `a` once. However, your threads do continue to update it.

Instead of just `print(a)` at the end of your code, try printing `a` in a loop, like this:

```
import threading,time

a = 1

def update():
    global a
    a += 1
    print ("updating")
    threading.Timer(1, update).start()

update()
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print(a)
```

When you do this, you will see that `a` is being updated, and that you can access its value outside the threads.